# Sqoop job for data transfer from Netezza to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I have a written a sqoop job to import data from a table in Netezza to HDFS. The job is created successfully and also when executed, starts a Map Reduce job. The job runs till **map 100% reduce 0%**  and gets stuck.The job never completes and data is not transferred at all. There is no error or exception observed.

I have few similar jobs for other tables of same database. Those execute properly and transfer data. What could be the possible reason for this behavior.

Below is configuration for sqoop job given in a option file.

--direct
--connect
jdbc:netezza://*url/database_name*
--username
abcd
--password
xyz
--table 
*table_name*
--split-by
*primary_key_column*
--target-dir
*hdfs_path*
-m
8

Comment: Can you post your sqoop import command?

Answer (score 2):

I removed the --direct option and job worked as expected. The direct option doesn't work if data is having ',' character in case of Netezza. Below is the exception error encountered with --direct:

**Unable to execute external table export
org.netezza.error.NzSQLException: ERROR:  found delim ',' in a data field, specify escapeChar '\' option in the external table definition**

Comment: I'm having this same issue.  I think this pretty much makes the `--direct` options useless... i would never know if my data has delimiters... and it would just hang jobs i'm depending on.

Comment: I just had the same issue, adding `--input-escaped-by '\' \
--escaped-by '\'` worked like a charm